# LIBGDX PNG screen capture cannot open file with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, libgdx

I make a screen capture using the function below:

```
public static String saveScreenshotNamePath(String name){
    try{
        FileHandle fh;
        fh = Gdx.files.external(name + ".png");
        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
        return fh.file().getAbsolutePath();
    }catch (Exception e){
        return "";
    }        
}

public void saveScreenshotFromGame(){
    path_to_saved_google = saveScreenshotNamePath("google");
}
```

I then want to open that image with an Intent but I when I open it I only see an [hourglass picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YRjT.png) . Why does this happen, I can see the picture correctly in the Image Gallery a few seconds later.

```
@Override 
public void openImage() {
    File file = new File(path_to_saved_google);

    media_scanner = new SingleMediaScanner(this, file); 
    try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "image/png");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```